# send outbound message to Marketo

Tags: marketo

Is it possible to send an outbound message from Salesforce to Marketo? I have a use case where I need to send fields from a custom object to Marketo via an outbound message and have the message parsed by Marketo and can then send out an email with the information that was sent via the outbound message.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible. There is a [native sync between Marketo and Salesforce](http://pages2.marketo.com/rs/marketob2/images/Marketo-and-SFDC-for-New-Customers.pdf), so it is possible to send custom object data from Salesforce to Marketo.

You would then have to set up a trigger campaign in Marketo to read custom object data and send the email. The trigger for this campaign would be a new record was added to a custom object. Then you would have to set up a [flow step of sending an email](http://developers.marketo.com/blog/sending-an-email-with-dynamic-content-from-marketo-using-the-api/) in the trigger campaign. In the email template, you would need to include tokens for the data needed from the custom object.